# Is there a way to add a click event to open a url in a highcharter plot without shiny?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I am trying to make a map plot using highcharter in which the points can be clicked to access their associated url. I've created the following simplified version of what I am doing (I'm doing a mapbubble plot instead) to illustrate my code. What am I doing wrong? Note: I have also tried this.point.options.url in the javascript section of the code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)

data("USArrests", package = "datasets")
USArrests = mutate(USArrests, "woe-name" = rownames(USArrests))
USArrests[["url"]] = c("https://www.google.com/", "https://www.wikipedia.org/")

hcmap(map = "countries/us/us-all", data = USArrests,
      joinBy = "woe-name", value = "UrbanPop", name = "Urban Population",
  allowPointSelect = TRUE) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    point = list(
      events = list(
        click = JS("function() {
                        window.open(point.url);
                      }"
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues with your code:

1. The map tile is a `map` and not a `point`, thus, your option file should link the event handler to `map` and not `point`.
2. To access the `url`you have to use a parameter in your JS function via which you can access the url eventually.

```
hcmap(map = "countries/us/us-all", data = USArrests,
      joinBy = "woe-name", value = "UrbanPop", name = "Urban Population",
      allowPointSelect = TRUE) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    map = list(
      events = list(
        click = JS("function(self) { 
                      window.open(self.point.url);
                   }"
        )
      )
    )
  )
```